# How can make jquery noconflict this code

Tags: jquery

Please help me to make the JQuery "noconflict" this code.
This is for "Navbar fixed on scrolling (with transition)".
And this is for navbar.

```
//Hello, world!
//This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in     
//Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.


$(document).ready(function() {
    /**
     * This object controls the nav bar. Implement the add and remove
     * action over the elements of the nav bar that we want to change.
     *
     * @type {{flagAdd: boolean, elements: string[], add: Function, remove: Function}}
     */
    var myNavBar = {
        flagAdd: true,
        elements: [],
        init: function(elements) {
            this.elements = elements;
        },
        add: function() {
            if (this.flagAdd) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById(this.elements[i]).className += " fixed-theme";
                }
                this.flagAdd = false;
            }
        },
        remove: function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
                document.getElementById(this.elements[i]).className = document
                    .getElementById(this.elements[i]).className.replace(/(?:^|\s)fixed-theme(?!\S)/g, '');
            }
            this.flagAdd = true;
        }
    };
    /**
     * Init the object. Pass the object the array of elements
     * that we want to change when the scroll goes down
     */
    myNavBar.init(["header", "header-container", "brand"]);
    /**
     * Function that manage the direction
     * of the scroll
     */
    function offSetManager() {
        var yOffset = 0;
        var currYOffSet = window.pageYOffset;
        if (yOffset < currYOffSet) {
            myNavBar.add();
        } else if (currYOffSet == yOffset) {
            myNavBar.remove();
        }
    }
    /**
     * bind to the document scroll detection
     */
    window.onscroll = function(e) {
            offSetManager();
        }
        /**
         * We have to do a first detectation of offset because the page
         * could be load with scroll down set.
         */
    offSetManager();
});
```

Comment: whit what library does this conflicts?

Comment: i downt know what library it is.

Comment: find out what library it is and get back to the question when you find out

Comment: these are my console error

Comment: custom.js:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
    at Object.add (custom.js:22)
    at offSetManager (custom.js:58)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (custom.js:77)
    at j (jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2)
add @ custom.js:22
offSetManager @ custom.js:58
(anonymous) @ custom.js:77
j @ jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2
fireWith @ jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2
ready @ jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2
J @ jquery.min.1.11.2.js:2